# Problema en android

Tags: android, android-studio

/*Estoy desarrollando una app, pero al momento de intentar poner una `searchView` me está causando este problema, esto es lo que tengo y me causa un error esta comentado en la parte de abajo donde esta el error.*/

la linea de error es:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'void
>   android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$OnQueryTextListener)'
>   on a null object reference at
>   com.example.igo.menudeopciones.onCreate(menudeopciones.java:56)

la linea 56:

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener( SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
```

este es mi Código:

```
@Override public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) { String locacion = searchView.getQuery().toString(); List
    <Address> addressList = null;
                    if(locacion !=null || !locacion.equals("")){
                        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(menudeopciones.this);
                        try {
                            addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locacion, 1);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Address address=addressList.get(0);
                        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(),address.getLongitude());
                        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(locacion));
                        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,10));
                    }
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Comment: deberias agregar el error, o la linea 54 no sabemos cual es

Comment: **listo esta cmentado todo el codigo gracias por el comentario**

Comment: y que dice el error?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$OnQueryTextListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.igo.menudeopciones.onCreate(menudeopciones.java:56) la linea 56 corresponde a la linea comentada

Comment: En la configuracion de tu elemento cambia tu `android: actionViewClass` a `app: actionViewClass`

Comment: dentro del xml de mi searchView no me permite ,¿si es ahi donde me comentas que devo de gregar la linea o me setoy equivocando?

Comment: @alexisGonzalezGarcia en el archivo xml al declarar el item, si estas utilizando la biblioteca de soporte debes de cambiarlo por : `app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"` [Documentacion](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/action-views#java)